# Topological type of complement of Heegaard curves in Heegaard surface $(\Sigma - \alpha - \beta)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, surfaces, heegaard-floer-homology

Suppose $(\Sigma, \alpha, \beta)$ is a genus-$g$ Heegaard diagram for a closed, oriented $3$-manifold $Y$, i.e. $\Sigma$ is an orientable genus-$g$ surface, and $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_g)$ and $(\beta_1, \dots, \beta_g)$ are two $g$-tuples of disjoint, homologically independent curves in $\Sigma$ (no relation imposed between $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

**I'm wondering if it's possible in general to determine the topological (or just homological) type of $\Sigma - \alpha - \beta$.**

If one were to give me any concrete Heegaard diagram, it wouldn't be hard to do this, but I'm unable to find a general pattern. Certainly, $\Sigma - \alpha$ is homeomorphic to a disk with $2g-1$ holes, and then the $\beta$-curves complicate (or simplify!) things. There are two holes for each $\alpha_i$, $i \ge 2$, and one for $\alpha_1$ (the $1$ is interchangeable with any $i$ here).

For example:

- if a $\beta$-curve $\beta_i$ only intersects one $\alpha$-curve, $\alpha_j$, at two points, this will create two additional disks as connected components (think of the genus-$1$ diagram for $S^1 \times S^2$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parallel, and perform a finger move on $\beta$).
- if a $\beta$-curve is homologically equal to some sum of $\alpha$-curves, $[\beta_k] = \sum_{i_j} [\alpha_{i_j}]$ and is disjoint from $\alpha$, then $\beta_k$ will split $\Sigma - \alpha$ into two components, one with a hole for each $i_j$, and one with all the other holes, plus an additional one created by $\beta_k$.
- if a $\beta$-curve intersects only one $\alpha$-curve transversely at one point, it turns the two holes corresponding to the $\alpha$-curve into one.

I've done some computations and, for the genus-$1$ diagram for $L(p,q)$, the result should be a disjoint union of $q$ disks, and for the genus-$g$ diagram for $S^3$, it should be a disk with $g-1$ holes.

I believe that the main factors should be the number of intersection points between the $\alpha$ and $\beta$-curves and the *order* in which each $\beta_i$ intersects the $\alpha$-curves. I would also be very happy if someone gave me a link to a computer program instead of an explanation.

**NB:** in the question [Irreducibility of a Heegaard splitting from its Heegaard diagram](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273435/irreducibility-of-a-heegaard-splitting-from-its-heegaard-diagram), I found mme's comment interesting, especially the part "I guess I don't know how Heegaard diagrams are usually encoded in a computer, but I imagine you should have easy access to the homology of the complements of the curves."

Answer (score 3):

My standing assumption is that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ systems of curves have been isotopes into minimal position (and thus $\Sigma - (\alpha \cup \beta)$ has no bigons).

There are two cases.

In the first, the two curve systems “bind” the Heegaard surface.  That is, $\Sigma - (\alpha \cup \beta)$ is a union of disks.  In this case you can get relations among the number of disks, their numbers of sides, the number of intersections between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and the Euler characteristic of $\Sigma$.

In the second case, the two systems do not bind. So there is an essential simple curve $\gamma$ in $\Sigma$ which is disjoint from both systems.  So $\gamma$ bounds a disk in both handlebodies.  Thus the splitting is *reducible*. Often the first move in dealing with such splitting is to reduce them: that is, cut along the resulting two-sphere and cap off the resulting boundary with three-balls.

Comment: By the definition of the Euler characteristic, I guess the number of disks in the first case should be $|\alpha \cap \beta| + \chi(\Sigma)$. Thanks!

Also, could you elaborate a bit on the "reduction" procedure? If one removes the resulting $2$-sphere, one gets two disjoint $3$-manifolds with boundary $S^2$. Do you mean that I cap each component off with a $3$-ball and get two closed $3$-manifolds, which should somehow be simpler than the original one?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct. Furthermore, if $\gamma$ is separating, then the pair of new three-manifolds come with induced Heegaard diagrams of their own. If $\gamma$ is non-separating then one of the new manifolds is a copy of $S^1 \times S^2$.

Comment: Thank you, fixed.